# Iterate over . csv file --> write into two dictionaries

Tags: csv, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

The `csv` looks like this:

```
2016-04-01 02:17    16.7    51.9
2016-04-01 02:18    16.7    51.9
2016-04-01 02:19    16.6    52.0
2016-04-01 02:20    16.6    52.2
2016-04-01 02:21    16.7    52.2
2016-04-01 02:22    16.7    52.1
2016-04-01 02:23    16.6    52.2
2016-04-01 02:24    16.6    52.2
2016-04-01 02:25    16.6    52.2
```

The File logs Temp and Humidity from a Sensor every Minute. Every Measurement is a row in the `cvs`file.

I'd like to iterate over this file and add rows, depending on the time to dictionaries. 
So one dictionary should hold all rows from `now`until `now - 24hours` and the other one should hold all rows from `now` until `now - 1week`. `Now`is the current time, the script was started.
I'm not certain on how to do that with on iteration (if possible).
This is how I open the file and define the TimeRow:

```
for row in f_reader:
    stringRowDate = row[0]
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringRowDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    stringDateNow = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    DateNow = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringDateNow,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

My Code with the `csv`File open:

```
if Date >= DateNow:
    continue
elif Date >= (DateNow - timedelta(weeks=1)):
    data_Week = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in f_reader}
rownum +=1
```

`data_Week`is the Dictionary that now holds all rows from the file from `now` to `1 Week` before now.

Can I, by using the same Iteration add every row within `24hours`to another  Dictionary (`data_24`)?

Comment: is the file sorted by dates?

Comment: edited the question, yes the file is sorted by dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check each line individually instead of sending all the rest of the data into one dict:

```
week_ago = (DateNow - timedelta(weeks=1))
day_ago = (DateNow - timedelta(days=1))
data_Week = {}
data_24 = {}
#data_before = {}

for row in f_reader:
    stringRowDate = row[0]
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringRowDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    if Date >= day_ago:
        data_24[row[0]] = row[1:]
    elif Date >= week_ago:
        data_Week[row[0]] = row[1:]
    else:
        continue
        #data_before[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

although this means that a lot of conditionals are checked unnecessarily if the file is conveniently sorted, in which case you can just keep track of the current `split_time` to indicate when to switch dict and `current_data` which will point to one of the dicts to put the dates into:

```
#first is the value to signal to go to next group
data_sorter = iter([(week_ago,None), #None placeholder to not keep data from before week_ago
                    (day_ago,data_Week),
                    (None,data_24)]) #no split for last one, just take the rest of data until end of reader
split_time,current_data = next(data_sorter)
for row in f_reader:
    stringRowDate = row[0]
    Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringRowDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    if split_time is not None and (Date > split_time):
        split_time,current_data = next(data_sorter)
    if current_data is not None: #make sure there is no placeholder
        current_data[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Depending what else is involved in your program it might be more convenient to use a generator so that there is no need for placeholders:

```
from operator import lt #used only for the default check_f
def split_by_time(reader,*split_times, check_f=lt):
    split_times = iter(split_times)
    split_time = next(split_times,None)
    current_data = {}
    for line in reader:
        row_time,*row_data = line
        if split_time is not None and check_f(split_time,row_time):
            yield current_data
            split_time = next(split_times,None)
            current_data = {}
        current_data[row_time] = row_data
    yield current_data


def check_limit(split_date, date_from_file):
    "convert the string date from file to a datetime object for comparison"
    return split_date < datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from_file,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

times = list(split_by_time(f_reader,
                        week_ago,day_ago, 
                        check_f=check_limit))

print("from before a week ago:\n",times[0])
print("from a week ago to a day ago:\n",times[1])
print("since yesterday:\n",times[2])
```

but that's probably more then you really need, I just really like generators. :D

Comment: thanks that was what I needed :-) thanks for the generator stuff as well but I don't think I am going to need them

Comment: I know, but I've been itching to make a coroutine ever since I saw [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) and made my first ever coroutine with this example (very close to generator I did provide) but I doubted you'd have any use for it since it is used so drastically differently.  I just made it for the fun of making it!